# What does alias not found mean if it is showing up in every terminal window I open after downloading Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I'm new to *Python/programming* in general. I downloaded *Anaconda* in an attempt to use *Python3*, and now every time I open a terminal window it says:

```
-bash: alias: added: not found
-bash: alias: by: not found
-bash: alias: Anaconda3: not found
-bash: alias: 2019.03: not found
-bash: alias: installer: not found
```

What does this mean/how do I resolve this?

Comment: Is there a line that says something like `alias added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer` in your `.bashrc` ?

Comment: @MrPromethee My .bashrc is empty